# How to apply distinct on memo datatype in visual basic access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the Visual basic access 2007 to create a Tool.Now my getting stuck as I have to apply distinct on Memo data type.But I am getting the error

"the field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add access 2010 memo fields.Try inserting or pasting less data"

I have tried the below mentioned query to get the distinct records from memo field.

select distinct CAS from table1.

Answer (score 2):

Access doesn't really let you do a distinct on a memo field.  It may either throw that error, or it could truncate the data after 255 characters.

If you don't need more than 255 characters then you could do a distinct on Left(FieldName, 255).  Otherwise something like this might help you: [Error message when you run a query in Access: "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896950)